# ERROR in PUT request (Angular 4 w/ NodeJs API REST)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm trying to make a crud in angular 4 using an api rest wrote in nodejs.

I was following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/3zpdnujI_B0?t=2239

But when the guy starts to make the PUT methot, doesn't worked for me...

I'm searching the solution for about 2 days

My PROJECT is here: https://stackblitz.com/github/Mauricio-vieira/newRepository

My API REST worte in NodeJs is here: https://github.com/Mauricio-vieira/apinode

(it starts with: "node server.js"),
(the mysql file is in the instruction to make the db/tables)

Glad if you could help me :)

Comment: can you add more details on what error

Comment: Yes, Just give me a minute

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Comment: did you try the same api with postman?

Comment: Yes, and it worked perfectly :(
(All the requests: get, post, put, delete)

Comment: well your stackblitz code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue lies here, you do not need to pass id for put, and your API does not take that as a parameter

```
let url = `${this.produtosUrl}/:10`;
```

change this to just

```
let url = `${this.produtosUrl}`;
```

and

```
updateProduto (produto: Produto): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.produtosUrl, produto, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`updated produto id=${produto.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateProduto'))
    );
  }
```

also on your node server,

Try using CORS module in Node.js server:

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Not working :( still having "Failed to load http://localhost:8080/produtos: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404."

Comment: Actually it is working , this error means that you need to enable CORS on your node api

Comment: if you really want to check you can open in incognito mode and see

Comment: Hmm, I'll try, I'm with cors extension on chrome... Still have to enable on the api?

Comment: hmm then no need! but just compare the request with postman and see what you are missing

Comment: Body on postman: [{"produto_id":10,"nome":"test","descricao":"testt","valor":10,"src":"testt"}]

with content-type: application/json works